# Is a way to authenticate into github to download private repos in AWS Codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, github, aws-codebuild, private-repository

Is there is a way to authenticate into github and download private company repos using the codebuild.yml file when using aws codebuild

Answer (score 1):

AWS CodeBuild uses the **CodeStarConnections** to connect to your public or private repository, when you are configuring Source in Codebuild, you will get options to

- Select your Source Provider like S3, Codecommit, GitHub, GitHub Enterprise, and Bitbucket.
- then For Repository, connect using **OAuth** or **Personal Access Token** of the source provider, this would create a code star connection that you could also use in some other build project.
- Specify your **branch, a pull request, commit ID, tag, or reference, and a commit ID**.
- Do some other configuration and you are set your source provider.

[image]